# bold portion of text selected with the mouse using javascript and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use javascript & css to create a little tool that will allow the user to select an area of text(whole word, part of a word, single character) with the mouse and then click a button that will then bold that selection.

I have 2 pieces working: I can bold the whole area, and I can write the mouse selection to the console.

But I can't figure out how to only bold the portion of text that was selected with the mouse.

I have a jsfiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/75EwZ/4/

Here's the code:

```
$(".boldtrigger").click(function() {
    var selection = getSelText();
    console.log('selected value', selection);
    //only bold text that is selected
    //get contents of .text
    //replace selected section with <span class="selectedText"></span>
    //ex:  user selects the word "the" with the mouse:
    //<div class="text">Testing the waters</div> becomes:
    //<div class="text">Testing <span class="selectedText">the</span> waters</div>
    //then bold contents of .selectedText
    $(".text").toggleClass("bold");
});

function getSelText()
{
    var txt = '';
    if (window.getSelection)
      { txt = window.getSelection(); }
      else if (document.getSelection)
      { txt = document.getSelection(); }
      else if (document.selection)
     { txt = document.selection.createRange().text; }
     else return;
     return txt;
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the method *surroundContents* on the Range of the selection. Unfortunately that function is not supported in every browser, so you will need to take care of that.

```
 var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
 if(selection.toString().length > 2){
        var newNode = document.createElement("span");
        newNode.setAttribute("class", "selectedText");
        range.surroundContents(newNode);       
 }
```

Working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EAuLt/).

See the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range.surroundContents).

Answer (score 1):

You should see the document.execCommand method :
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla

Answer (score -1):

Go through this tutorial [Get Selected text through jquery](http://designhuntr.com/get-highlighted-text-using-jquery-code-snippet/). use the same code to get the selected section then on button click replace the same with `<b>"selected text"</b>`.